# How to check if a key (on the keyboard) is being held down?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Basically title. I need a function which works kind of like a crouch button - the character crouches only when the down arrow key is being HELD, not only pressed once. How do I make it work? Here is what I have tried but it doesn't work. Thanks in advance!!!!!

```
document.onkeydown = function (event) {
    let key = event.key;
    while (key ==  "ArrowDown") {
        character.style.width = 50 + "px";
        character.style.height = 30 + "px";
        character.style.top = 115 + "px";
    }
}
```

Comment: you can handle the `onKeyDown` and OnKeyUp if there is no keyup event then it is held down.

Comment: The time between keydown and keyup events represent the duration of a key being held down. When you get the keydown, go into crouch mode and listen for a keyup to stop crouching.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`keydown` event is continuously fired when you hold down any key and when you release the key, `keyup` event is fired.

To achieve what you are trying to do, add the styles to the character when `keydown` event is fired and on `keyup` event remove those styles from the character.

Following code snippet shows an example:

```js
const character = document.querySelector('.character');

document.body.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
  character.classList.add('crouch');
});

document.body.addEventListener('keyup', (event) => {
  character.classList.remove('crouch');
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: yellow;
  position: relative;
}

.crouch {
  height: 50px;
  top: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="character">Press any key</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you might be looking for is to simply put this at the beginning of the code block within the event listener:

```
if (!e.repeat) return
```